# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable, cross_validation Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

When trying to use `cross_validation` I get the error above. I'm not really sure how to solve this. Since I'm pretty new to this so I'd really appreciate any help.

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl, math
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm, cross_validation
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
df = df [['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume',]]
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] *  100
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] *  100

df = df[['Adj. Close','HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. Volume']]

forecast_col = 'Adj. Close'
df.fillna(-99999, inplace=True)

forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01*len(df)))

df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

x = np.array(df.drop(['label'],1))
y = np.array(df['label'])
x = preprocessing.scale(x)
y = np.array(df['label'])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation(x, y, test_size=0.2)

clf = LinearRegression
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

accuracy = clf.score(x_test, y_test)

print(accuracy)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name `cross_validation` identifies a module, the name of the function is `train_test_split` (see [sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html)).

Use the dot notation to call the function instead:

```
cross_validation.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
```